# Session variables are lost after some time or instantly in php

Tags: php, session-variables

Whenever the user login on my page the `username` is stored as a `$_SESSION` variable like so:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

where `$username` is the email address of the user and further user is assumed to be logged in. What I have observed is that my user is automatically logged out instantly after logging in or after few times. Are my session variables lost or what other problem should be?

My `session_start()` is always at the beginning and there is no space above it, so this is not the problem.

The part of my login code when login is successful is:

```
 if ($usererror != 1 && $passworderror != 1 && $conferror != 1) {

    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    $_SESSION["password"] = $password;

    header('Location:/dashboard_test/index.php');
}
```

The first page that accepts login has the first few lines as:

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: the default lifetime of php session is 1440 seconds (24 mins)

Comment: How often is garbage collection set to occur in your `php.ini` file?

Comment: @CodeIsLife usually it's lost after a second the user logins and immediately he/she is logged out.

Comment: make sure the current session is loaded in the script with session_start();

If you are sure the code is correct,  the problem could very possibly be the PHP server does not have the correct permissions to write to the session files directory.

Comment: Yes it's loaded with session_start();

Comment: @wogsland It is session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

Comment: Is your login code to long to post? Perhaps we could glean something from that...

Comment: @Rasclatt I have added few chunks of my code

Comment: `header('Location:http:\dashboard_test\index.php')` – that Location header does not make any sense. The value has to be an absolute URL, and use forward slashes.

Comment: Yes, sorry. In the code it is correct. I wrote wrong over here by mistake. I have edited it. if i am writing www.meetings.alnnovative.com/dashboard_test/index.php it says page not found, so I have to write Location:/dashboard_test/index.php

Comment: After what time it goes to logout did you notice that ? because default life time of session is 24 mins only .

Comment: @Divakarcool usually after a second it is logged out.